# Creating a map function in Java that takes an array and a function as inputs

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking to create a function in Java that takes a different function and an array as inputs, and outputs an array where each element in the original array has been run through the input function.

The assignment I've been given says it wants the map function to have the following signature.

```
public static <R, D> R[] map(Function<R, D> function, D[] array)
```

The assignment also gives a few examples, which I've copied as text below since the site won't let me include a screenshot yet.

```
// Example 1
Function<Integer, Integer> function = new CalculateSuccessor();
Integer[] integerArray = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5};
PrintArray(map(function, integerArray)); // map returns {2, 4, 5, 3, 6}

// Example 2
Function<Integer, String> anotherFunction = new CalculateLength();
String[] stringArray = { "Java", "C++", "Smalltalk" };
PrintArray(map(anotherFunction, stringArray)); // map returns {4, 3, 9}

// Example 3
Function<Double, Double> tripleFunction = new CalculateTriple();
Double[] doubleArray = { 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0 };
PrintArray(map(tripleFunction, doubleArray)); // map returns {6.0, 12.0, 15.0, 3.0}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *assignment also* must have asked you to give it a try on your own!

Comment: @nullpointer that is one interesting assignment btw - not that trivial at all

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the assignment is wrong, because that `Function` must be declared as `Function<D, R> function`, read it as "a function that transforms from D to R". Implementing such a method is fairly trivial actually:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <R, D> R[] map(Function<D, R> function, D[] array) {
    return (R[]) Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(function)
            .toArray(Object[]::new);
}
```

with a small caveat. Creating a generic array in java is not allowed, *but declaring one* is and also arrays are *covariant* meaning you can assign one to another, unlike generics for example. One example how you would use your method would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map(x -> x + 1, new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 })));
}
```

**EDIT**

Read Didier comments below, basically what is written above is wrong, I am leaving it for learning purposes (including my failure here). You could do it, but you need to pass an additional parameter to that method, for example:

```
public static <R, D> R[] map(Function<D, R> function, D[] array, IntFunction<R[]> func) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(function)
            .toArray(func);
}
```

This is much like `ReferencePipeline::toArray` does it.

Another option would be to return a `Object[]` and then use `Arrays::copyOf`:

```
public static <R, D> Object[] map(Function<D, R> function, D[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(function)
            .toArray();
}

Integer[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Object[] obj = map(x -> x + 1, input);
Integer[] result = Arrays.copyOf(obj, obj.length, Integer[].class);
```

Comment: `Integer[] result = map(x -> x + 1, new Integer[] {1, 2, 3})` => `ClassCastException`. It does not make sense to cast to `(R[])` like this because it is 100% guaranteed that the cast is wrong, except when `R` is `Object`. The requirement to return a `R[]` is, in fact, impossible to satisfy.

Comment: @DidierL excellent comment, thank you for reminding me that I can be quite an idiot sometimes, much appreciated! I've added two options that will fix this, but indeed neither matches the initial method signature